# What's an XM-Profiler?

Tags: ingress

The Aegis Nova event in Tokyo is featuring a special challenge called "XM-Profiler". Most of the websites about the Aegis Tokyo event are in Japanese so we cannot get the details on what it is. Could someone speaking Japanese or attending the event please enlighten us about its details?

Comment: I've never heard about that. Where did you see that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're just mocking me or not but anyway here are two simple search results : https://goo.gl/B1iDRR and https://goo.gl/tjJsK9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer!

XM-profiler are Japanese vending machines. Here is the resource:

http://en.rocketnews24.com/2016/07/21/before-pokemon-go-there-was-ingress-and-its-first-xm-profiler-illumination-portal-is-in-japan/

Comment: Just to clarify: It's not a vending machine as it doesn't actually vend anything.